How can I make SQL output readable?
I'm trying to find an Emacs replacement for SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). I have managed to query my Microsoft SQL Server from Emacs – and what a task that was! – through SQL Mode. However, the output is utterly unreadable.

Org-Babel has been suggested, but it is only slightly better

and the LaTeX export is laughable.

Abusing the -o parameter of sqlcmd has been of no help. The files that this exports to are the same as what SQL Mode gets.

Compared to the output of a serious SQL tool like SSMS, this is quite lacking.

What other approaches can I take from within Emacs?

Since you have a satisfactory solution with SSMS, why go the Emacs route at all? There are many things that are better done outside of Emacs. Sacrilege, I know - but it is true.

@NickD Because I'm on a Linux machine and SSMS is native to Windows.

That's a very good reason indeed. All I can say is Best of luck! and ask you to blog assiduously about your progress.

I'll add that the original output in the *SQL* buffer is going to be a lot more readable than your screenshot if you M-x toggle-truncate-lines.  You can scroll-left and scroll-right as needed.

If you're creating a log of query results then org may be very useful; but if you're just trying to interact with the database and have no need of any log then the *SQL* buffer has always been good enough for my purposes (and if the output is too verbose, I just limit the query to what I actually need).  YMMV of course.

@phils Your suggestion was amazing, but took extra work. Give me a few minutes to edit my answer.

@NickD Thank you for wishing me luck. My answer shows that I've now got quite a bit further.

Bottom Line Up Front
These still suck compared to SSMS, but they are the only tolerable Emacs solutions that I've seen. My suggestion for a Linux user who wants a good Microsoft SQL Server IDE is to give up on Emacs and either use DBeaver or Azure Data Studio. If you want to compromise, then use Emacs to write your queries and something else to run them.
How to Connect
Let me show you how I connect Emacs to Microsoft SQL Server, from scratch. This might not seem relevant, but this knowledge will be helpful for writing your own configurations.
Boot Your SQL box
This is left as an exercise for the reader.
Locate sqlcmd
Find where you have sqlcmd installed. On my Linux machine, this is done with
which sqlcmd

and returns /opt/mssql-tools18/bin/sqlcmd.
If you do not have it installed already, then do so.
Make SQL Mode Recognise sqlcmd
By default, SQL mode uses osql. I've never seen it work, so replace it with your sqlcmd's path. On my machine, this is
(setq sql-ms-program "/opt/mssql-tools18/bin/sqlcmd")

Configure sqlcmd
The defaults for how sqlcmd connects to your server include the deprecated -n. We will remove that here. Also, if you don't add the -C parameter to sqlcmd's options, then you have to go through some pain to connect. Let's skip that as well. -w is kept as its default.
(setq sql-ms-options `("-w" "300" "-C"))

Connect
There are many ways to do this. For example, running sql-ms will give you plenty of prompts. Personally, I do this
(setq sql-connection-alist
      '((my-connect (sql-product 'ms)
                    (sql-server "your-sever-ip-dont-use-the-name")
                    (sql-user "your-user")
                    (sql-password "your-password-escape-special-characters-using-a-\-before-them")
                    (sql-database "your-db"))))

and then I can just run sql-connect and give my-connect at the prompt.
Make it Look Good
Option 1: Better Settings for SQL Mode
As the question shows, this is very ugly by default. To make it not ugly, we need to customise both Emacs and how it talks to sqlcmd.
First, change sql-ms-options to make the output of sqlcmd super wide. As per the documentation, 65535 is as high as the width can go.
(setq sql-ms-options `("-w" "65535" "-C"))

If you sql-connect after just this, then your output will be ugly. Try it now.
Fortunately, all that is missing is some Emacs config in your window of ugly SQL results. Credit to phils for suggesting this.
toggle-truncate-lines

If you run this in your SQLi[Microsoft] buffer (I use M-x toggle-truncate-lines), then you will find the following tolerable output

To scroll, you want C-x < and to read the horizontal scrolling documentation

For reference, the SQL-relevant lines in my .emacs are these
(add-hook 'sql-mode-hook (lambda ()
                             (setq-local indent-tabs-mode nil)
                             (sql-set-product 'ms)))

(setq sql-ms-program "/opt/mssql-tools18/bin/sqlcmd")
(setq sql-ms-options `("-w" "65535" "-C"))

(setq sql-connection-alist
      '((my-connect (sql-product 'ms)
                    (sql-server "your-sever-ip-dont-use-the-name")
                    (sql-user "your-user")
                    (sql-password "your-password-escape-special-characters-using-a-\-before-them")
                    (sql-database "your-db"))))

(add-hook 'sql-interactive-mode-hook #'toggle-truncate-lines)

Option 2: Better Parameters for Org-mode
As mentioned earlier, sql-ms-options passes in -w 300 by default. This control the screen width in sqlcmd. If you explicitly do not provide this, then the org-mode and LaTeX export appearance improves. These aren't good solutions, but they're better than what you had.
Here is the superior org-mode approach
#+name: my-query
#+begin_src sql :exports both :cmdline -S myip -U myuser -P "mypassword" -C :engine mssql 
SELECT * FROM sys.databases
GO
#+end_src

and its output's appearance in org-mode

as well as LaTeX.

Option 3: lsp-mssql
lsp-mssql looks good. The readme incorrectly says that it's not on MELPA. In principle, you can install it from there just fine. However, I have never successfully got it working in Emacs. I always get stuck in the same place as this user. If you are able to get it to work, then it appears to be a good solution. That said, if it's anything like the VS Code plugin that it's based  off of, then expect it to be very buggy.

See C-h v org-export-with-sub-superscripts to fix your issue with underscores in LaTeX.  Also C-h i g (org)Export Settings.

@phils Is there any way to embed that behaviour in to the org-mode header? I'd rather export as normal but have some flag in the document telling LaTeX to treat it specially.

(Also, was that issue the reason that "these still suck compared to SSMS"?  I'm not sure what else you might have been hoping for...)

I don't use org much, and don't know the answer to your question offhand. I've simply encountered the underscore thing before.  (I'd guess it's possible, but you'll have to research that yourself.)

@phils SSMS has a few other nice features, like being able to change the column width and order after you've got the output. It also makes the results appear in a new buffer, which is handy.

@phils Seems like you just need to stick #+OPTIONS: ^:nil in the header.

In general, it is more flexible to use #+OPTIONS: ^:{}: that way, only x_{a} or x^{a}  does sub/superscripts but you can get them if you need them.

You can change column order in an Org mode table with M-<left> or M-<right>. I suspect however that Org tables are going to be too slow for anything other than toy examples: it takes quite a while for Org babel to process the output of the database to a table and moving columns around is equally time-consuming. I suspect that you will have trouble with tables of more than 100 rows or so (it took me 3 minutes (!) to move a column in a 640-row table). I think I'm running native-compiled Org mode at this point (I usually run completely uncompiled code), but I don't know yet how to check.

I'm now certain that I'm running with native-compiled Org mode and things are much faster: the 640-row table is generated in a few seconds and moving a column is of the same order of magnitude. So you should be able to deal with a few hundred rows. But the algorithm is still almost quadratic AFAICT, so you'll quickly run into bottlenecks for larger tables. I'm guessing a few thousand  rows would be the practical limit on my machine.

One thing that seems to help a lot when moving columns is to turn off org-indent-mode. Unfortunately, it does not help with the initial generation of the table when you run the source block: there orgtbl-to-generic seems to be the biggest culprit.
